# How to make a background image of a modal window appear simultaneously with a modal window, not before?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, twitter-bootstrap, background

I have a modal window with a background image as a background `css` property. The problem is that the background image appears much faster than the modal itself. How to make make them appear simultaneously?

Here is my HTML code of the modal window:

```
<div class="modal" id="regModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="regModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
    <div class="modal-dialog modal-dialog-center modal-carpet" style="min-height: 400px;">
        <div class="modal-content"></div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Here is a class `.modal`:

```
.modal {  
    border: none !important;
    overflow: hidden;
    background-position: center;
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
    right: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    left: 0;
    z-index: 1050;
    outline: 0;
    background: url('/img/carpet_simple.png') no-repeat fixed center;
}
```

And so `background: url('/img/carpet_simple.png') no-repeat fixed center;` appears instantaneously, much faster than the inner HTML code of the modal is rendered.

I tried this solution. It works but it is obviously not a good one. I just make a backgroung image appear 300ml later:

```
.pic {
    background: url('/img/carpet_simple.png') no-repeat fixed center;
}

$('.modal').on('shown.bs.modal', function() {    
    var timeOutId = setTimeout(function() {
        $("#regModal").addClass("pic");
        clearTimeout(timeOutId);
        delete(timeOutId);
    }, 280);
});

$('.modal').on('hide.bs.modal', function() {
    $("#regModal").removeClass("pic");
});
```

How to make a background appear simultaneously with a modal inner html code or at least a little after it? And without my solution.

Comment: Can you perhaps make a jsfiddle.net or a bootply.com demo we can see the issue on?

Comment: What @RobSchmuecker said.

Comment: Ok, I'll try. Never used it before, it'll take some time.

Comment: When/how is the contents of `<div class="modal-content"></div>` getting populated? Assuming it's through AJAX, in whatever handler you currently have to append/inject your HTML content, add a `.promise().done(function() {$("#regModal").addClass("pic");});`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use javascript events for the modal. For example `loaded.bs.modal`;This event is fired when the modal has loaded content using the remote option.

```
$('#myModal').on('loaded.bs.modal', function (e) {
  // do something...
})
```

There are other events fired with the modal you can read about [here](http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#modals)